# Looking for a two way clamp two extend a pole

Tags: exterior, extension, pole

I'm looking for a clamp that can extend a 2" diameter pole with another pole.

Basically I'm trying to set up a [Ubiquiti Litebeam](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014S1JJVM) but the pole I'm attaching it to isn't tall enough for line of sight to the other building.

What I want is something like this picture but the poles will be free standing in the air, not againt a wall.  Imagine that the one on the left is attached to the building and is sticking out of the roof.  I want to get another pole (the one on the right) to be clamped on (possible two clamps) to the pole sticking out of the roof.

What kind of clamp am I looking for?

[image]

EDIT: Here's an image of what I want, don't know what it's called.
[image]

Comment: Not sure this is a Home Improvement question...

Comment: @keshlam What do you consider home improvement? I'm trying to modify something on the exterior of my house.

Comment: Part identification for stuff like this is very well within scope here.

Answer (score 1):

That is called a Shelly pole/mast clamp.  If you are extending a fairly light load like you show, an antenna or other such fairly light, non load bearing use, then this is fine.

For anything structural, or carrying live loads, this is the wrong product as you want to carry the load directly from top to bottom not laterally like this product does.

Comment: I want to attach a 1 meter pole.  Do you think I should use two clamps? And do they sell these in North America? I'm looking online and they all seem to come from the UK.  Is there something similar sold in NA?

Comment: I don't know.  I only found out what it was called by finding the picture you found online and looking at the page on which it was hosted to find its name.